# dynamics ax 2009 landing page

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

I would like to redirect some of my users to a specific form in aot when they open dynamics ax 2009.  What is the best way to that?  Today, they directly go to the role center page.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're asking 2 questions here: how to open a specific form from the code, and how to get something done automatically when AX is opened.

I don't have an access to AX at this moment but the following code should help you with the first question.

```
FormRun formRun;
;

formRun = new MenuFunction(menuitemdisplaystr(___FormMenuItemName___), MenuItemType::Display).create(new Args(this));
formRun.init();
formRun.run();
formRun.detach();
```

As to the second question, you just need to add your code to method `StartupPost` of either `Application` or `Info` class.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to create a menu item for the form.

Then in the Info class, modify the startupPost() method by calling the menu item:

new MenuFunction(menuitemDisplayStr(YourMenuItem), MenuItemType::Display).run();